# How could i create carbon object from given datetime structure?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I use laravel, i need to create **carbon object** from the **timestamp** that i received.

TimeStamp : '**yy-mm-dd HH:mm**'

ex. '**2016-12-20 10:26**'

Is this possible ?

Or Any other solution ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `Carbon::parse('2016-12-20 10:26');`, it will return a `Carbon` object.

Answer (score 15):

### Here is the [official way from the Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation):

> Finally, if you find yourself inheriting a \DateTime instance from another library, fear not! You can create a Carbon instance via a friendly instance() function.

```
$dt = new \DateTime('first day of January 2008');   // <== instance from another API
$carbon = Carbon::instance($dt);
echo get_class($carbon);                               // 'Carbon\Carbon'
echo $carbon->toDateTimeString();                      // 2008-01-01 00:00:00
```

<sub>Also [shown here](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/231#issuecomment-66875268)</sub>

Comment: This only works if you get a `DateTime` object, though. OP indicates they're getting what looks like a string.

Comment: Since DateTime was in the question title, I figured it was relevant.

Comment: @farzan Then you could upvote this answer so more people consider it.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `parse()`:

```
Carbon::parse($dateString);
```

Or you can use `$dates` property to create Carbon instance automatically for the column:

```
protected $dates = ['custom_date'];
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on [carbon doc](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), you can convert date string to carbon object like:
1) `Carbon::parse('1975-05-21 22:23:00.123456')`
2) `Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz);`