# How to parse a faker dateTimeBetween with Carbon in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, faker

I am generating fake dates between a specific interval with faker. Generated dates result `TIMESTAMP` formate. I need to format it like 'Y-m-d' for insert into MySQL database table.

```
$events = $faker->dateTimeBetween('-30 days', '+30 days');
$dateFormate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp('Y-m-d H:i:s', $events )->format('Y-m-d');
```

But in the time of database seeding it gives an error

```
 [ErrorException]
  A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Comment: What does _"But its not working properly"_ mean? Where's the issue?
 Faker? Carbon? When you're trying to insert the data? Errors? Invalid data?

Comment: Sorry . I edited the question with the specific error.

Comment: `Carbon::createFromTimestamp()` takes a _timestamp (unix timestamp)_ as first argument and not a DateTime-object, which `$faker->dateTimeBetween()` returns. Check out  [Carbons documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Could you post the output of `dd($events)`

Comment: This was helpful for me in understanding how to use Carbon and Faker together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798012/470749

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using both Carbon and the result from faker wrong (you don't need to use Carbon at all).

This row:

```
$events = $faker->dateTimeBetween('-30 days', '+30 days');
```

returns a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) instance. If you want to get the date in the format "Y-m-d" from a DateTime instance, all you need to do is to call [`DateTime:format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$dateFormat = $events->format('Y-m-d');
```

That should give you the date in the format you want.

Answer (score 2):

that will return a carbon instance.

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($faker->dateTimeBetween('now', '+7 days')->getTimestamp());
```